# for loop stops batch script

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-server-2012-r2

ok so been playing with this script and for some unknown reason it always crashes out (exits the prompt) when the script reaches the for statement, however if i simply copy and past these commands one by one into the cmd it works fine. can anyone tell me why this is or how i can get around this ? thanks

```
@echo off

CD C:\RemoteInstall\Boot\

set /p name=Enter the wim file name (no extension):

SET name=%name:~0%.wim

echo+ %name%

timeout >nul 2

FOR /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir "%name%" /b /s') do set p=%~a

SET p=%p:~0%

echo %p%

timeout >nul 2

xcopy "%p%" C:\imagefix\image /y
timeout >nul 2

pause
```

Comment: ok so i resolved this myself it turns out i had to escape the delims in the for statement `FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%name%" /b /s') do set p=%%~a`

Answer (score 0):

ok so i resolved this myself it turns out i had to escape the delims in the FOR statement, which now looks like this

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%name%" /b /s') do set p=%%~a
```